# Eclipselink query generation with IS NULL operator

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, isnull

I have 3 tables, RA, CC and EC. RA has a foreign key, 'ec' which maps to 'code' column in the EC table. RA also has another foreign key, 'sc' which maps to 'code' column in the CC table.

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery( name="getSettingsByCode, query="select object(o) from RA where  o.sc.code = :someCode and o.ec.code is null" )
})

public class RA implements java.io.Serializable {
@Id
private long id;

private Timestamp recupdatetime;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="SC")
private Cc sc;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="EC")
private Ec ec;
```

Entity for Cc

```
@Entity

public class Cc {

@OneToMany(mappedBy="sc")
private Set<RA> raCollection;
```

Entity for Ec

```
@Entity

public class Ec  {

@OneToMany(mappedBy="ec")
private Set<Recommendedalarmsetting> recommendedalarmsettingCollection;
```

When the namedQuery is executed, it generates the following sql,

```
[sql] SELECT t0.ID, t0.RECUPDATETIME, t0.EC, t0.SC FROM RA t0, EC t1 WHERE (
((t0.sc = ?) AND (t1.CODE IS NULL)) AND (t1.CODE = t0.ec))
```

Is this SQL generated correct?. I am not sure about the IS NULL operator generating a join to the EC table.

Comment: what is the identity of `Ec` ? If it is `code` then you should be doing `o.ec IS NULL` rather than `o.ec.code` ...

Comment: @BillyFrost
We are in the process of migrating from OpenJPA to Eclipselink and have a lot of queries that are in that format. This worked fine using OpenJPA so I wanted to know if there is any reason why the sql is generated that way.

Comment: Why it is generated? because the JPQL is non-optimum, and your previous JPA provider worked around it, and your new JPA provider doesn't ... perhaps.

Comment: IS NULL isn't generating the join, the "o.ec" in your where clause is.  Putting that requires providers to use an inner join to travers the relationship used to build the (CODE IS NULL) portion. If you want a left outer join, you should be using "select ra from RA ra left join ra.ec ec where  ra.sc.code = :someCode and ec.code is null" Or use o.ec IS NULL if the PK of ec is code as Billy mentioned above.